# Determine the volume of a solid

Tags: multiple-integral, iterated-integrals

Calculate the volume $V$ of the solid $G$, which is obtained when from the sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}<36$ is cut by the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$.  $G$ is given as:
$$G:=\{(x,y,z), x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}<36, x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1\}.$$

My solution:
$$V=\int_{-\sqrt{35} }^{\sqrt{35} } \! \int_{0}^{2\pi} \! \int_{1}^{\sqrt{36-z^{2}} } \! r \, dr  \, d\theta  \, dz = \frac{140}{3}\sqrt{35}\pi.$$

Can someone tell me if it is correct?

Comment: Can you explain your answer? It looks like you are integrating "tubes." Why are you restricting $z \in [-\sqrt{35}, \sqrt{35}]$? And why $r \in [1, \sqrt{36-z^2}]$?

Comment: I imagine $G$ to be in three pieces: (i) a cylinder for $z \in [-\sqrt{35}, \sqrt{35}]$, (ii and iii) top and bottom parts (arctic circle and antarctica) for $z>\sqrt{35}$ and $z < -\sqrt{35}$.  You can also do it by integrating tubes of radius $r$, thickness $dr$, and height $h_r$, with each having volume $2\pi r h_r dr$.

Comment: The original question was for the shape $G = \{(x,y,z):x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 36, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$.  My comments were for that case, and they were intended to help the original asker.   I observe that Robert Z unilaterally changed the question without asking clarification or confirmation from the original asker, and without regard to my comments.

Comment: @Michael Now the question is the original one. Are you still angry with me? ;-)

Comment: @RobertZ I am surprised you changed it back. My (incorrect) 
impression was that you would not care. When the asker asked 
this question, I gave timely and relevant feedback, yet my 
comments were ignored.  I came back a few hours later and 
found the question had been changed (which made my comments 
look confusing), but no note or clarification was given.  
That is why I made my further remarks. Thanks for your
understanding.  The asker can change the question yet again 
if she wants, it seems her thoughts were similar to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are cutting away the full cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$ from the sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}<36$, I guess the solid $G$ is given by
$$\{(x,y,z), x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}<36, x^{2}+y^{2}> 1\}.$$
In this case, your evaluation by using the cross-section method is correct.

Note that we can evaluate $V$ also by using the shadow method,
$$V=\int_{r=1 }^{6} \! \int_{0}^{2\pi} \! \int_{z=-\sqrt{36-r^{2}}}^{\sqrt{36-r^{2}} } 1  dz\,(r \, dr  \, d\theta)=4\pi\int_{r=1 }^{6}
\sqrt{36-r^{2}} rdr\\
=\frac{4\pi}{3}\left[-(36-r^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_1^6
=\frac{140}{3}\sqrt{35}\pi.$$

Comment: I have never before seen an answerer edit the question to actually _change_ the question.  There was not even any back-and-forth "do you mean the outside part not included in the cylinder, or the part inside the cylinder?"  You simply changed it.

Comment: @Michael I am sorry, but I am not following you.

Comment: The definition of $G$ was originally $G = \{(x,y,z) : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <36, x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$.  And it is clear from clicking the "edit" tab that you changed it (those edits are tracked).  Usually one would ask the asker for clarification, rather than just changing it unilaterally.

Comment: @Michael You are right but it was probably a typo. The statement says that the sphere is CUT by the cylinder.

Comment: There are two sides to a cut.  The original definition of $G$ seemed to specify which side was of interest.  In any case, your change ignored my previous comment, and seems to undermine it.

Comment: @Michael Two sides for $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$, but here we have $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$.

Comment: You just said "here we have $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. So, are you changing $G$ back to teh original definition?

Comment: @Michael the original statement says "cut by the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$".

Comment: You seem to be one of those people who assumes there is only one interpretation for any turn of a phrase.

Comment: @Michael I am sorry that you are disappointed but to me "cut by the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$" clearly means tha the full cylinder is removed.

Comment: That is not at all clear to me.

Comment: @Michael Now the question is the original one. Are you still angry with me? ;-)